# What is the Python equivalent of React's destructuring of properties in components?

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructuring

I have a dictionary / object with a lot of attributes. I want to pass its attributes as named arguments to a function in Python.

In React, I can use property destructuring:

```js
<Component {...props} attr={10} />
```

If `props` contains an attribute `attr`, it would be overwritten by 10.

In Python however, this does not work:

```py
props = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "attr": 3}

def foo(a=None, b=None, attr=None):
    ...

foo(**props, attr=10) # this fails
```

The error message is *got multiple values for keyword argument 'attr'*. Of course, a solution would be to remove the item beforehand. However, this seems rather clumsy and I'm curious if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: that's not possible in one go so you'll have to update the `props` before passing it to the function: `props.update(attr=10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.9+:

```py
props = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "attr": 3}

foo(**(props | dict(attr=10))
foo(**(props | {'attr': 10}))
```

Considering you are using Python 3.5+, you can use any of the following alternatives:

```py
props = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "attr": 3}

foo(**{**props, 'attr': 10})
foo(**{**props, **dict(attr=10)})
foo(**{**props, **{'attr': 10}})
```

If you are using a previous version of Python:

```py
from collections import ChainMap

foo(**ChainMap({'attr': 10}, props))
```

Keep in mind that in order to pass parameters to a function you need to follow this order:

- positional arguments
- keyword arguments
- `*args`
- `**kwargs`

Comment: Unfortunately, `foo(attr=10, **props)` fails with the same error message. The update strategy works. I hoped that it would be possible in one line.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf `dict.update` returns `None`...

Comment: @metatoaster, you are totally right. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Do note that this `**` expansion only became available in Python 3.5, so while generally this is fine to use, certain specific backwards compatibility will need the older solution in the linked thread.

Comment: Also probably worthwhile to add your answer to that other thread.

Comment: In Python 3.9 you also have the `|` union operator.

Comment: @iz_, that a great use of `|`!